# Connecting to Kestrel using the Dalli gem (or Heroku compatible gems to connect to Kestrel with memcached interface)

Tags: ruby, heroku, memcached, dalli, kestrel

I am unable to connect to [Kestrel](https://github.com/robey/kestrel) using the [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) (a memcached client) gem. Is dalli not compatible with kestrel?

```
require 'dalli'
dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:221133')
dc.set('abc', 123)
```

Doing this from IRB/Pry returns:

```
I, [2012-10-12T17:38:03.994201 #19524]  INFO -- : localhost:22133 failed (count: 2)
Dalli::RingError: No server available
from /Users/eli/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194-perf/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/ring.rb:45:in `server_for_key'
```

Yet doing the same thing using the memcached gem works fine:

```
require 'memcached'
mc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:221133')
mc.set('abc', 123)
mc.get('abc')
```

---

Note that the only reason I'm trying to switch to dalli from the memcached gem is because I am unable to get Heroku to install the memcached gem:

```
rlibmemcached_wrap.c: In function ‘Init_rlibmemcached’:
rlibmemcached_wrap.c:13776: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sasl_client_init’
rlibmemcached_wrap.c:13776: error: ‘SASL_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [rlibmemcached_wrap.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Dalli is not compatible with Kestrel. Dalli only uses the [binary memcache protocol](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/memcached/memcached/protocol-binary.txt), and Kestrel only uses the [text memcache protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt).

Heroku support has told me that the [memcached gem](https://github.com/evan/memcached) is not compatible with their Cedar stack.

Thus the best option for Kestrel support on Heroku is using the older [memcache-client gem](https://github.com/mperham/memcache-client), which is the predecessor to Dalli.